# luabind, std::vector return wrong values

Tags: c++, lua, stdvector, luabind

I have programm a test-function which return an std::vector.

```
std::vector<unsigned char> readFromSlave(unsigned int _bits) {
        std::vector<unsigned char> helpvector;
        helpvector.push_back((unsigned char) 10);
        helpvector.push_back((unsigned char) 20);
        helpvector.push_back((unsigned char) 30);
        helpvector.push_back((unsigned char) 40);
        return helpvector;
    }
```

and register it in lua like (important part of registering):

```
x.def("readFromSlave", &readFromSlave, luabind::return_stl_iterator);
```

and call the function in lua:

```
vector = readFromSlave(500);

for value in vector do
    print(value)
end
```

It works only partly, it return the correct number of elements, but the values aren't correct.

A sample output is:

```
128
83
0
1
```

What could be the problem?

(info) I have removed class and namepaces from the example to shortened it.

Comment: Are You intentionally casting an `int` value into `unsigned char`? I assume  Lua tries to convert it back (`tonumber()`) and misses some pieces.

Comment: I would use `unsigned char`, because this is a function for reading from an I2c-slave (which is based on 8Bit values). Moreover, I have tested the function with usigned int, and the result was that only the 3. and 4. value was printed right, the first two values were incorrect.

Comment: I gotta know, did this ever work? As far as I can tell, you can't even run what you're trying to do. You must return a vector reference for luabind to do the "return_stl_iterator" magic, otherwise you're copying the vector and the iterator no longer points to a vector that's alive. At least that's what happened to me. Right?